# sparql query if statement with retrieval and variable

Tags: if-statement, switch-statement, sparql, querying

My main need is to use something like switch cases in other programming languages.

I have a `?x g1:state (true OR false OR UNDEF)` The latest is a variable incoming from a REST API and I want to perform different things based on that value

What I want to achieve is: if `?x g1:state true`, bring me all the `true` triples. If it is `false`, bring me all the `false` triples that correspond. If the latest is undefined, bring me all the triples with whatever values. Something like this.

`Bind ( if ('+test+'=true, ?x g1:state true,  Bind ( if ('+test+'=false, ?x g1:state false, ?x g1:state ?y1) as ?y) as ?xf)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ι bypassed this obstacle with a different approach, outside the sparql query

```
var booleanvar = req.params.booleanvar

if (booleanvar==='true' || booleanvar==='false'){

        } else {
            booleanvar= '?'+booleanvar
        }
```

and then I just added a simple triple statement into the query

```
?x g1:state '+booleanvar+'
```